# wp_redirect not working in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, session

I am trying to create custom plugin in wordpress.
We want to create a case like if user is not logged in to the system then user should be redirected login page. I tried wp_redirect and wp_safe_redirect but it is not working. here is my code.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['game_login'])) {
   //Do Something
 }else{
   wp_redirect('login');
   exit():
 }
```

I am getting this warning

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:225) in wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

can someone suggest me in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons causing this issue.
Try this points and hope this may have a fix

1. Remove blank space from files that are showing error after php `?>` tag at end of file, But in your case
   it is from core file, So don't modify anything in terms of code just try to remove blank space at the
   ending of those files. Also remove blank space from bottom of files
   wp-config.php and functions.php
2. If the above point does not work add this code to your wp-config.php file

   `ob_start(); 
   error_reporting(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just start output buffers wherever unless you're specifically delaying the final output, such as modifying content on the `template_redirect`, using `add_shortcode`, or any numerous scenarios where you *intend* to buffer the output.

The code in your example should be encapsulated in a function and hooked to one of WordPress' many [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Typically this kind of function is added on the [`plugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) or [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hooks.

```
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_anonymous_users' );
function redirect_anonymous_users(){
    if( isset( $_SESSION['game_login'] ) ){
        // Do Something
    } else {
        wp_redirect('login');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried creating init hook. but i am getting error: The page isn’t redirecting properly.